# How can i read html page from json File

Tags: html, json

i have a json File and The Content of The file a Long html page, The issue is The output of The json Looks Like This as an example `{"resource_response":{"0":"\n","1":"\n","2":"<","3":"!","4":"d","5":"o","6":"c","7":"t","8":"y","9":"p","10":"e","11":" ","12":"h","13":"t","14":"m","15":"l"}}` This is My html page and The Code is <!doctype html> But The Code splited , so how can i make This Readable again ?

Comment: do you want to render the html code written in json file in your html page?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use this **Javascript code** in your HTML file and like this, add your JSON data inside the `<div>` tag with an id named `json_to_str`, the example is below:

```html
        <head>

            </head>
            <body>
           <! -- Your JSON inside div tag with id json_to_str --> 
            <div id="json_to_str">
{"resource_response":{"0":"\n","1":"\n","2":"<","3":"!","4":"d","5":"o","6":"c","7":"t","8":"y","9":"p","10":"e","11":" ","12":"h","13":"t","14":"m","15":"l"}}
</div>

  <script>

  // javascript code to formating

  var json_to_str = document.getElementById("json_to_str");
  var obj = JSON.parse(json_to_str.innerText);

  // getting obj of all character 
  let strListObj = obj["resource_response"];

  // string to store the result
  resStr = ""; 
  
  // loop for iterating through on obj
  for (var key in strListObj) 
 {
   if (strListObj.hasOwnProperty(key)) 
   {
      var val = strListObj[key];
      resStr += val
   }
   }
   
   // setting up the result string
   json_to_str.innerText = resStr;

</script>

</body>
```

hope it helps.

Comment: Hey Rohit  Thanks For you Helping, but This is Not What am Trying to achieve, what am trying To achieve is i want to Make the  output of The json readable again if you take a  closer again on The json content you will Notice it's a html code but the json splitting it to charters and The html code is broke, so i want to make it readable again so it will Print the output Like This <!doctype html> instead of This output {"resource_response":{"0":"\n","1":"\n","2":"<","3":"!","4":"d","5":"o","6":"c","7":"t","8":"y","9":"p","10":"e","11":" ","12":"h","13":"t","14":"m","15":"l"}}, Thanks

Comment: I just updated the code according to your need. check out.